# How to Flash-Swap on UniswapV3

Tags: flash-loans, uniswapv3

i need some help .I have already deployed the "pair flash" contract with hardhat , on uniswapV3 , now i need to know the  function to call . Thanks !
https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/guides/flash-integrations/final-contract

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange! Could you please add more details about what do you mean by "need to know the function to call"? What is the problem that you're encountering, specifically?

Answer (score 0):

got as far as deployment as well. when i enter the variables and try to transact (call flash) i get error. transaction will likely fail, because of gas estimation error. no idea what the work around is for this. i'm using binance smart chain, someone suggested that this type of transaction is not possible on bsc. anyone with suggestions. i'm starting to believe no one has ever gotten this to work lol. i get a similar error in the v2 flashswap

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/92285)